# webview to open sites of certain domain

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to make an app that opens all web pages of a certain site, for example www.yahoo.com, in the webview, but all other web pages in the defaultbrowser. Here is the code that I am using but can not quite get it work.

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://www.yahoo.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
            // the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
        // another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

It looks to me that this code should work, but when i load yahoo it still goes to an outside browser. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a different way to do it.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    String urlHost = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
    switch (urlHost) {
        case "yahoo.com":
            return false;
        case "www.yahoo.com":
            return false;
        case "m.yahoo.com":
            return false;
        default:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getHost()` usually returns just the domain name, or sometimes with `www.` prefixed to it. It never contains an `http://` protocol AFAIK. Try using:

```
if ((Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("yahoo.com")) ||  (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.yahoo.com")) ||  (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("m.yahoo.com"))) {
    //Your code
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that code does not fix the problem. When yahoo.com is opened in the browser instead of the webview, the url is m.yahoo.com. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should help you

```
private WebView mWebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_yahoo);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```